# Changing embed src attribute dynamically using file dialog

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I implemented a HTML page which runs locally on a Linux machine (using the most current firefox versions). It is used to embed a plugin which I have programmed.

At the moment, I statically pass a file path, the plugin has to load, that is hard-coded in the HTML file:

```
<embed id="embed1" type="application/x-bbx" src="/tmp/testfile.bbx"></embed>
```

The HTML page is generated for all `.bbx` files. I'm currently trying to figure out how I can avoid the hard-coded path by adding an `<input type="file">` element. The aim is to dynamically change the loaded file (specified by `src`) to avoid the need of generating the HTML page for all `.bbx` files.

As browsers do not allow access to the file path: how I can change the `embed`'s source according to the loaded file?

For several technical reasons, I would like to avoid using JQuery. Also note, that the page is run solely locally by specific users.

**EDIT 1:** The plugin is scriptable, i.e. I can invoke functions on and pass parameters to the plugin using JavaScript. Thus, it would suffice to get the whole file path and pass it to the plugin which in turn does the rest internally.

**EDIT 2:** For clarification: I want to avoid the burden of having the user enter the file path manually, which is why I intended to use `<input type="file">`

Comment: So, you wan to use javascript?

Comment: Yes, I do. But nothing more, i.e. I don't want to (or technically cannot) use languages other than JS and HTML

Answer (score 2):

```
var Target = "/tmp/testfile2.bbx";
var Source = document.getElementById('embed1');
var Clone = Source.cloneNode(true);
Clone.setAttribute('src',Target);
Source.parentNode.replaceChild(Clone,Source);
```

But history of browser gets no event here... so .back() will work incorrectly.
Thats how I got here today. Hope this helps. And sorry if a was not fluxed to the right moment. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, this should do it!

```
<script>
var embed1 = document.getElementById('embed1');
embed1.src = 'your path';
</script>
```

Comment: This does not help, because I still don't get a file path specified by the user (unless he enters it manually, which is what I want to avoid)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/7u601e8f/)

```
<input type="text" id="path" name="path" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Change it" onclick="changePath()">
<embed id="embed1" type="application/x-bbx" src="/tmp/testfile.bbx"></embed>

<script>
function changePath() {
    var e = document.getElementById('path');
    var val = e.value;
    var embed1 = document.getElementById('embed1');
    embed1.src = val;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid having the user type in the file path manually. This is why I thought about using the `<input type="file">` tag.